# download csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, url

I'm trying to download historical stock trading from my country with R. I tried with the download.file() function. Indeed, a file is downloaded but is an empty spreadsheet. Obviously, if I use this url in my browser the file I downloaded is in fact the one I want.

I would love to do it with quantmod, but that package only applies to larger markets

```
url<-"https://www.ccbolsa.cl/apps/script/detalleaccion/Transaccion.asp?Nemo=AFPCAPITAL&Menu=H"
destfile <- "/home/hector/TxHistoricas.xls"
download.file(url, destfile)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All I'm getting is a javascripted html file.  Btw, you are not using httr at all in your code

Comment: I think it's an html file that renders to the appearance of an excel file when opened in a browser.  I could open it via the browser but not via R.  It's not something you're doing wrong, it is something to do with the nature of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can jury-rig something like this if you don't want to use selenium:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(stringr)

URL <- "https://www.ccbolsa.cl/apps/script/detalleaccion/Transaccion.asp?Nemo=AFPCAPITAL&Menu=H"
```

Get initial URL:

```
res <- html_session(URL, timeout(30))
```

It embeds a form that it uses javascript to submit to get the form:

```
inputs <- html_nodes(res, "input")
```

It uses the last javascript entry to do a redirect on page load, so we need the location of it:

```
scripts <- html_nodes(res, "script")
action <- html_text(scripts[[length(scripts)]])
```

This is the new URL to submit to:

```
base_url <- "https://www.ccbolsa.cl/apps/script/detalleaccion"
loc <- str_match(action, '\\.action *= *"(.*)"')[,2]
doc_url <- sprintf("%s/%s", base_url, loc)
```

Gather up all the query params:

```
query <- lapply(inputs, xml_attr, "value")
names(query) <- sapply(inputs, xml_attr, "name")
```

Now we have to make a new `POST` request with the query encoded as "form", using and providing a redirect URL (timeout was necessary for me). This write the "xls" content to a file:

```
ret <- POST(doc_url, 
            body=query, 
            encode="form",
            add_headers(Referer=URL),
            write_disk("fil.xls", overwrite=TRUE),
            timeout(30))
```

It *says* it's an XLS file:

```
ret$headers$`content-type`
## [1] "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

but it's really an HTML table, so you can really just do:

```
ret <- POST(doc_url, 
            body=query, 
            encode="form",
            add_headers(Referer=URL),
            timeout(30))

doc <- read_html(content(ret, as="text"))
dat <- html_table(html_nodes(doc, "table"), fill=TRUE)
```

to get what you're looking for (there are two ugly tables in the `dat` list and you may want to use `header=TRUE` as an additional parameter to `html_table`).

I am not sure how "dynamic" this solution but that's test-able/verifiable.

Comment: When I run this piece of code, I get the following error doc <- read_html(content(ret, as="text")) "Error: Could not find the "read html" function" I need some additional package?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I get a giant object, 2467 observations, which is fine, but 17240 variables. The resulting file is too large to properly handle it. Can I change any parameter to prevent that ?.

Comment: Aye, I saw that (I was surprised when the table conversion took so long! :-) I don't have an account on that site and don't even really know what I'm looking at data-wise, so I have no idea how to control what they do. You can trim it down to only the variables you need tho.

Comment: Finally, of the two objects in the list, only one contained the data of my interest. Specifically, dat[[2]]. With this data frame I'm working, which is also of appropriate size. Thank you very much for your answer!